# problemas en script ( bash permiso denegado)

Tags: linux, shell-script

tengo que hacer un script que hace varias acciones una de ellas cambiar el propietario de un archivo pero me dice todo el rato  bash acceso denegado, el unico trozo de codigo que no me va es el siguiente
es un case

```
read -p "Dime el fichero y ruta que  quieres cambiar de propietario" nom
read -p "Dime el propietario nuevo" pro
nom=$nom
pro=$pro
chown $pro $nom
;;
```

Comment: ¿qué pasos realizas exactamente? ¿cuándo te da el permiso denegado? seguramente debas ejecutar con `sudo` para poder hacer el cambio libremente

Comment: Sería interesante ver los detalles del fichero que quieres cambiar. Pero si el fichero pertenece a otro usuario no podrás cambiar el propietario sin usar `sudo`

Comment: a ver gracias por vuestros comentarios pero...si estoy dentro de un script no soy supuestamente root ? no necesitaria sudo no? otra cosa lo estoy probando con un fichero con permisos 777 por si era eso pero me dice lo mismo

Comment: Una pregunta, el nombre del archivo tiene espacios???  Quizá deberías poner las comillas de turno en la asignación y/o en la llamada

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1):

1.- Si estás dentro de un script, no tienes por qué estar con un usuario root. Puedes comprobar tu usuario actual con `whoami`

2.- Si en efecto, estás con root, deberías tener permisos.

3.- Si no estás con root, deberías ejecutar el script con `sudo script.sh`

4.- Si tienes permisos. Es decir, si al hacerlo con lo anterior no te ha funcionado, comprueba que no haya espacios en los nombres de archivos. Puedes evitar el problema poniendo entre comillas los nombres correspondientes. Es posible que al no tener los espacios no estés accediendo al fichero correcto.

```
read -p "Dime el fichero y ruta que  quieres cambiar de propietario" nom
read -p "Dime el propietario nuevo" pro
nom="$nom"
pro="$pro"
chown "$pro" "$nom"
;;
```

Un ejemplo rápido sobre cómo usar o no las comillas puede cambiar tus resultados.

```
alejandro@DESKTOP-784E0PG:/mnt/c/Users/Alejandro/prueba$ ls -lrta
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 alejandro alejandro 4096 Nov 23 13:37  ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alejandro alejandro    0 Nov 23 13:37 'fichero con espacios en el nombre'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alejandro alejandro    0 Nov 23 13:39  fichero
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alejandro alejandro    8 Nov 23 13:39 'fichero con espacios'
drwxrwxrwx 1 alejandro alejandro 4096 Nov 23 13:39  .
alejandro@DESKTOP-784E0PG:/mnt/c/Users/Alejandro/prueba$ cat "fichero con espacios"
pepito

alejandro@DESKTOP-784E0PG:/mnt/c/Users/Alejandro/prueba$ cat fichero con espacios
cat: con: No such file or directory
cat: espacios: No such file or directory
alejandro@DESKTOP-784E0PG:/mnt/c/Users/Alejandro/prueba$ cat fichero
alejandro@DESKTOP-784E0PG:/mnt/c/Users/Alejandro/prueba$
alejandro@DESKTOP-784E0PG:/mnt/c/Users/Alejandro/prueba$ chown alejandro $nombre
chown: cannot access 'con': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access 'espacios': No such file or directory
alejandro@DESKTOP-784E0PG:/mnt/c/Users/Alejandro/prueba$ chown alejandro "$nombre"
alejandro@DESKTOP-784E0PG:/mnt/c/Users/Alejandro/prueba$
```